# Shopware 6 how create a product with media with the Admin API?

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

How can i create a product with media with the Shopware 6 Admin API PHP SDK ?

[Shopware 6 Admin API PHP SDK](https://github.com/vienthuong/shopware-php-sdk)

I know how to create a product with following snippet.

```
$productRepository->create([
    'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
    'name' => 'New Product',
    'taxId' => $product->taxId,
    'price' => $product->price,
    'productNumber' => $product->productNumber . random_int(10, 1000),
    'stock' => $product->stock,
    'media' => $product->media, //Not working
], $context);
```

And how to upload media from a URL with following snippet.

```
$mediaService->uploadMediaFromUrl($mediaId, $url, 'jpg', 'test-media');
```

But how can i add the media to the product ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `media` association is a collection of `product_media` entities, serving as mappings to `media` entities. After you upload a file to create a `media` entity from a url, you can use that id to create `product_media` mappings when creating the product.

```php
$mediaService->uploadMediaFromUrl($mediaId1, $url, 'jpg', 'foo');
$mediaService->uploadMediaFromUrl($mediaId2, $url, 'jpg', 'bar');

$productRepository->create([
    // ...
    'media' => [
        [
            'position' => 1,
            'mediaId' => $mediaId1,
        ],
        [
            'position' => 2,
            'mediaId' => $mediaId2,
        ],
    ],
], $context);
```